# maven - strange class not found exception

Tags: java, maven-2

Hy,

I have a maven project.

> mvn clean install

works perfect.

When deploying on my jboss server i receive this strange error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: javax.ws.rs.core.Response
    at org.jboss.mx.loading.LoadMgr3.beginLoadTask(LoadMgr3.java:212)
    at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassImpl(RepositoryClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:415)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 93 more
```

I've checked if artifact exists and it's there.

> C:\Users\Cristian.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\jaxrs-api\2.0-beta-4\

Does anyone have a work-around for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your dependecy isn't in the deployed application. You may have to change the "provided" scope to "compile"

---

**Resources :**

- [Maven - Dependecy scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)

Comment: I've changed it for: jaxrs-api artifact and now i receive: "15:23:22,549 ERROR [[/optin]] Error configuring application listener of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBo
otstrap
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap"